# How to change constraint definition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I created a table in PostgreSQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  Id varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (Id ~ '^[a-z0-9]{3,15}$'),
  ...
);
```

This will automatically create a constraint called `table1_id_check`.

Now I would like to change the check constraint to

```
(Id ~ '^[a-z0-9]{3,}$')
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL as a single statement without dropping the constraint and recreating it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple statements within a transaction works on all SQL dbms that support using this DDL in a transaction.

```
begin transaction;
    alter table table1
    drop constraint table1_id_check;

    alter table table1 
    add constraint table1_id_check CHECK (Id ~ '^[a-z0-9]{3,}$');
commit;
```

PostgreSQL lets you use multiple clauses within an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
alter table table1
drop constraint table1_id_check,
add constraint table1_id_check CHECK (Id ~ '^[a-z0-9]{3,}$');
```